# How to parse and put parts of string into an array?

Tags: php, regex

I have links like these two:

```
http://www.something.com/something/edit/id/$id/type/$type
```

And

```
http://www.something.com/something/edit/id/:id/type/:type/collection/:collection
```

Since, I'm not good with PHP's RegEx, I'd like to extract this from these two links:

```
// first link
array(
    'id', 'type',
);

// second link
array('id', 'type', 'collection');
```

Is it possilbe to parse and extract these `$id` and `:type` parts of string with PHP's RegEx?

Thank you all for your help!

---

**EDIT:**

For all you down-voters, please undestand that I want to extract all these items starting with `$` or `:` and ending with an `/` or an empty string, and to push those matched in that format into a new array.

Comment: You probably don't want to use regular expressions for this anyway.

Comment: I want to extract all those parts starting with `$` or `:` and ending with an `/` or an empty string, into an array.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - How to do this then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex with a [look behind assertion](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.assertions.php):

```
$link = 'http://www.something.com/something/edit/id/$id/type/$type';
// or
$link = 'http://www.something.com/something/edit/id/:id/type/:type/collection/:collection';

preg_match_all('~(?<=[:$])[^/]+~', $link, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Explanation:

```
~            Pattern delimiter
(?<=[:$])    Lookbehind assertion. Matches : or $
[^/]+        Any character except of / - multiple times
~            Pattern delimiter
```

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer. Thank thee!

Comment: Ok. You might reword your question entirely. If anybody does clearly understand the problem immediately, it might get upvoted. When people reading the phrases "url, parse, variables, PHP" they likely tend to say this *has already been answered*, however, I think what you are doing is at the end something special.

Comment: `I want to extract all these items starting with $ or :`. I think these two characters are not shown on the final output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, excluded them using the look-behind assertion (and it looks like OP wants that). If you want to keep those characters, simplify the pattern to: `~[:$][^/]+~`

Comment: i think he wants the value just after to `/id`, `/type`, `/collection` .

Comment: Good idea and obviously at matches the needs of OP :)

Answer (score 1):

First remove any unnecessary parts of link

```
$string = str_replace('http://www.something.com/something/edit/', '', $url);
```

Than `explode` rest of string

```
$string = rtrim($string, '/');
$array = explode('/', $string);
$values = [];
$keys = [];

foreach ($array as $i => $param) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        $keys[] = $param;
    } else {
        $values[] = $param;
    }
}

$returnArray = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Comment: Nice, but @hek2mgl example is better. Thank thee.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this,

```
(?<=\/id\/)[^\/]+|\/type\/\K[^\/]*|collection\/\K[^\/\n]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iM7vX1/16)

Code:

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOD
http://www.something.com/something/edit/id/\$id/type/\$type
http://www.something.com/something/edit/id/:id/type/:type/collection/:collection
EOD;
preg_match_all('~(?<=\/id\/)[^\/\n]+|\/type\/\K[^\/\n]*|collection\/\K[^\/\n]*~', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "$id"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "$type"
    [2]=>
    string(3) ":id"
    [3]=>
    string(5) ":type"
    [4]=>
    string(11) ":collection"
  }
}
```